# Prove that every planar Euler graph has an Euler-cycle that doesn't crosses itself.

Tags: graph-theory

I am a first year math student, and I'm studying some exercises for my graph theory exam. This exercise I didn't understand very well:

> Prove that every planar Euler (simple) graph has an Euler-cycle that doesn't
>   crosses itself.

Here an idea for a proof:

Let $G$ a planar Euler graph and let $C=(v_0,...,v_k)$ a Euler-cycle with minimum number of crossings. Suppose $C$ has a crossing. [Some brilliant reasoning]. Now $C'$ has one crossing less, but we supposed $C$ has a mininum number of crossings. Contradiction!

But maybe it can be proven in a complete different way.

Comment: I guess the idea is that if there is a crossing at vertex $v$, say, the cycle goes $a,v,b$ and then later $x,v,y$, then you make the path "bounce off itself" instead of crossing itself by doing $a,v,y$ and $x,v,b$ instead. Needs some work, though.

Comment: @GerryMyerson So something like, if there is an crossing at the vertix $v$ just don't take the path that crosses it, but just go left or right. ?

Comment: I think you want to break a Euler circuit that does cross itself into a series of loops. Wherever two loops intersect at more than two points, break the two loops into segments which allow a non-intersecting path.

Comment: Yes, Kasper, that's what I had in mind. You have to convince yourself that doing this doesn't create new crossings somewhere else.

Comment: I not sure in my understanding of this terminology.  The graph $G_0$ with the set of vertices ${1,2,3,4,5}$ and the set of edges ${(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5,3), (3,1)}$ has an Euler cycle $1-2-3-4-5-1$? This cycle crosses itself? *** From another point of view, I have an idea. If a graph $G$ has an Euler cycle, then every vertex of $G$ has an even degree, and maybe then by induction we can easily show the existence of an Euler cycle on $G$ without crossings (provided we have a respective definition of a cycle without crossings).